# expression for $\sqrt{-3}$ in $\mathbb Z_7$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I cannot understand this.If I have to write expression for  $\sqrt{-3}$ in $\mathbb Z_7$.

how should I write it?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb Z_7$?

Comment: Write down $a^2$ for all elements $a\in\mathbb Z_7$. Does the result equal $-3\pmod 7$ for some input $a$?

Comment: Is there another reading of this question? That would give an answer of $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_7\,:\,x^2\equiv 4\mod 7\}$.

Comment: First you should decide whether or not $\sqrt{-3}$ is really an element of $\mathbb{Z}/7$.

Comment: What is $\Bbb{Z}_7$ for you? If it is the field of residue classes of integers modulo $7$, then others have already answered your question. If (less likely, but possible) $\Bbb{Z}_7$ is the ring of 7-adic integers, then there is more to do... I do not criticize anyone who interpreted the question as being about residue classes. Normally an asker interested in the adics would say so. It is just that the question is meaningful and interesting in both cases.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen no it's just a field in this case...

Comment: Ok (+1 for communicating with us and clarifying). Do observe that in the residue class fields we have no way of knowing which of the two (or none!) solutions of $x^2\equiv-3\pmod7$ is intended. Unlike in the reals there is no nice way of calling one half of the elements `positive', and attempt to find a single valued square root. If the origin of the problem is to solve a quadratic equation over $\Bbb{Z}_7$, then this is no concern, because both choices lead to a meaningful solution!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen this was a question my proffesor gave for exercise.which says In $\mathbb Z_7$ give a reasonable interpretation for the expression $\sqrt{-3}$ .so, will there be two expressions for this?

Comment: Correct. There is no useful way of selecting between the two solutions. Not unexpectedly the solutions are negatives of each other (or, if you want to make it sound fancier, additive inverses of each other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean $\mathbb Z_7$, you need to find the element $x$ in $\mathbb Z_7$ such that $x^2=-3$.

For example, $3^2 = 2 = -5$ in $\mathbb Z_7$.

Comment: No problem. by the way, "to find the element $x$"; this need not be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb Z_7$ $-3 = 4$, and the square roots of $3$ are $2$ and $-2$. From basic polynomials theory we know that there can be no more than 2 solutions to a quadratic equation, so this are the only roots.

Comment: Careful about that; $1$ has four square-roots in $\mathbb{Z}_8$

Comment: @Michael thanks. But it is true in fields, isn't it?